# Rollback not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a user table, and I have 5 records.

I deleted two records, then executed the rollback command, it executed successfully.

But that deleted two records not recovered.

The user table engine is [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).

Comment: The title of your question is *very* mighty! It sounds like Spanish for *y'all guys at MySQL are doping while coding and y'all dev end-users have been using doped db!*..lol. MySQL DB is a big deal man! You can't just throw such accusation at it :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to rollback your transaction as the table engine is InnoDB.
[image]

Anyways here is the correct way to do transactions,

```
SET autocommit=0;
START TRANSACTION; 
Your Query here.
ROLLBACK;
```

and make sure that you are not using `COMMIT` after the Query which you need to rollback. Refer
[Table Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html) and [Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). And When a DB connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode by default. This means that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is automatically committed right after it is executed. So if you need to do transactions yourself, you must turn off the autocommit mode by `AUTOCOMMIT = 0`. Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html) for more info.

Comment: i use directly start transac and rollback. but i don't use SET autocommit=0; . but for me trasnaction rollback worked. i would like to know purpose of this SET autocommit=0;

Comment: @Bharanikumar: When a DB connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode by default. This means that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is automatically committed right after it is executed. So if you need to do transactions yourself, you must turn off the autocommit mode by `set AUTOCOMMIT = 0`. Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html

Comment: You shouldn't need to turn off auto-commit before using a transaction. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html. "To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement. With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state."

Answer (score 6):

```
By default, MySQL starts the session
for each new connection with
autocommit enabled,
```

You could set autocommit mode disable before running your query

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

ref:

**[Link 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)**

**[Link 2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transactions-with-different-apis.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you already do command

```
start transaction;
```

before the query delete.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET autocommit=0;
BEGIN;
.
.
.
ROLLBACK;
```

[START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you were locking tables, but I ran into the same problem where it seemed like rollback wasn't working.

Within my transaction I called "LOCK TABLES...", which

> implicitly commits any active transaction before attempting to lock
>   the tables

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

I ended up locking outside of (before) the transaction, as that was the first thing I was doing in the transaction anyway. Alternatively, you can do as the docs suggest:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but i has checked the  innodb support

First:
Verify if the Engine INNODB is Available: with this:

```
mysql> show engines;
```

if INNODB is disabled: then

Second:
go to the file "my.ini", in my case is in C:\AppServ\mysql 
in this file removes the "#" of the line

```
#default-storage-engine=INNODB -> default-storage-engine=INNODB
```

and the line skip-innodb add "#"

```
skip-innodb -> #skip-innodb
```

Third:
save and restart mysql service, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one important thing to mention: to re-enable autocommit after transaction is done.

```
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO ..
    UPDATE <table> ..
COMMIT;
SET autocommit = 1;
```

Otherwise anything you do after disabling `autocommit` even without transaction will require you to explicitly commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL Workbench you can turn off Auto-commit transactions in 'Query' tab.
And don't forget to use "COMMIT;" after the Query which you need to rollback.

Answer (score -1):

Even for me rollback was not working for InnoDB engine.
But adding `begin;` statement after `start transaction;` made the fix.

**<sub>This worked for me</sub>**

```sql
SET autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
begin;
-- DML query goes here
rollback;
SET autocommit = 1;
```

But

**<sub>This doesn't worked for me</sub>**

```sql
SET autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
-- DML query goes here
rollback;
SET autocommit = 1;
```

Really i don't know the reason, If anyone knows please comment here.